# Magento 2.1: Markup language in order confirmation email

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, order-email

I made an order in my Magento store and received the order confirmation in my mailbox. However, the markup didn't converted to normal text. It keeps `{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}` as text and the email also contains some HTML tags.

[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: It is fixed. I upvoted and accepted your answer. Thanks! Sorry for the late reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, directive `{{htmlescape}}` and `{{escapehtml}}` are obsolete. Use `{{var}}` instead.

See more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html